# LIMIT/OFFSET by DISTINCT column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to select all posts with all their related tags:

```
SELECT p.*, pt.name AS tag_name, pt.id AS tag_id FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN posts_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
```

So i get something like this:

```
 p.id | p.name | p.content | tag_name | tag_id
  1   | Yahoo  | ...       | first    | 1
  1   | Yahoo  | ...       | second   | 2
  2   | Google | ...       | second   | 2
  2   | Google | ...       | third    | 3
```

I know when selecting records this way it is possible to get number of records through `COUNT(p.id)` for example, but i didn't discover how to set `OFFSET` (how many records skip from the beginning) and `LIMIT` (how many records return at all) **according to unique post ID**.

Now it's obviously working in the way, that it's skipping/limiting the number of records, but not the number of real posts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want all "tag" rows for *N* posts starting at offset *O*:

```
   SELECT p.*, pt.name AS tag_name, pt.id AS tag_id
     FROM (SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT {N} OFFSET {O}) p
LEFT JOIN posts_tags pt
          ON pt.post_id = p.id
```

**Addendum**

Here's one way to do it using `DENSE_RANK` to limit just by the posts themselves:

```
   SELECT p.id, p.name, p.content, pt.name as tag_name, pt.id AS tag_id
     FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS dr, posts.*
             FROM posts) p
LEFT JOIN posts_tags pt
          ON pt.post_id = p.id
    WHERE dr BETWEEN {N} AND {N + O}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you a lot for your very useful answer. And quick question : does `BETWEEN {N} AND {N + O}` equal with `BETWEEN {offset} AND {limit}` ?

Comment: `0` based offset and limit should be `BETWEEN #{offset} + 1 AND #{offset} + #{limit}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with PostgreSQL, but (if I understand your question right) I think `ROW_NUMBER()` is the right place to start.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
  Tag_Name, Tag_ID
FROM
  (
  SELECT P.ID, P.Name AS Tag_Name, P.Content, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.ID, PT.Tag_ID) AS RowNum
  FROM Posts AS P LEFT JOIN Posts_Tags AS PT ON P.Post_ID = P.ID
  ) AS X
WHERE
  RowNum BETWEEN 101 AND 200
```

This should do the trick in MS SQL, you may need to adjust the syntax.

Comment: Upvoters, have you tried running this query?  Analytic functions are a good idea, but ROW_NUMBER() gives the exact behavior the OP does _not_ want.  Additionally the column projection is incomplete (two cols instead of five) and PT.Tag_Id does not exist except as an alias in the OP's data set.